# Convert SQL statement to JPQL statement

Tags: sql, jpa, jpql

I wonder how I convert this SQL statement to JPQL:

```
SELECT sum(price) AS Income, count(*) AS Passages, Station.Name 
FROM Passage
INNER JOIN station ON passage.stationId = station.id
GROUP BY Station.Name
```

wouldnt it be something like this:

```
SELECT sum(price) AS Income, count(p) AS Passages, s.Name FROM Passage p
INNER JOIN station s     
ON p.stationId = s.id GROUP BY s.Name
```

?

Comment: Too lazy to check all of it now, but to begin with in JPA you deal with objects, not with their ids. So, `ON p.station = s ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem solved with:

```sql
SELECT count(p), sum(p.price), s 
FROM Passage p 
INNER JOIN p.station s 
GROUP BY s.name;
```

Answer (score 4):

There is no `ON` in `JPQL` (JPA 2.0), but you can do an implicit join and use the WHERE clause:

Assuming that the entity `Passage` the atriburo `StationID` is the same type of object that the attribute `id` of the entity `Station`.

```
SELECT SUM(s.price) Income, COUNT(p) Passages, s.Name
FROM Passage p, Station s
WHERE p.stationId = s.id
GROUP BY s.Name
```

It is recommended that if the question can add entities Station Passage and to give a correct answer.